# How to get values from customer dates/Datepicker using ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Here i got small issue i created date selection box where customer can choose 4 options like **Day,Week,Month,Custom date**

1.If customer chooses **Day** the from & to date should be current day.

2.If customer chooses **Week**then from date should start Sunday & to date should be current date in week.

3. If customer chooses **Month** then from date should start month starting date & to date should be current date in month.
4. if customer chooses **Custom date then customer should pick his from date and to date.

below is my code i have to wrote code in this below format

code for selecting dates

```
   <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-label>Report Type</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="reportType">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of reportTypes" [value]="opt.TypeId">{{opt.Type}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
 </ion-col>

    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-label>Report Type</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="reportType">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of reportTypes" [value]="opt.TypeId">{{opt.Type}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
 </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

 Code for getting custom dropdown on selecting custom

    <ion-row *ngIf="reportType==10">
      <ion-col>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>From Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="reportDataFromDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
  <ion-label>To Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="reportDataToDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Typscript code:

```
 this.reportTypes=[{TypeId:1,Type:'Day'},{TypeId:7,Type:'Week'},{TypeId:30,Type:'Month'},{TypeId:10,Type:'Custom Date'}]
```

//////////////calculate date by reportTypes

```
  calculateFromAndToDateByReportype(reportType){
   var days; // Days you want to subtract
   var currdate = new Date();

   if(reportType==1){
      this.reportDataFromDate=currdate;
   this.reportDataToDate=currdate;
   }
   else {
     var last = new Date(currdate.getTime() - (reportType * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   this.reportDataFromDate=last;
   this.reportDataToDate=currdate;
   }

  }
```

Till now i got **Day** ,

But unable to get the Week i.e Starts from Sunday to Current day in Week

Month :-From date should be Month starting date and to date should be month current date

current date: from date should be the selected value and to date should be selected value

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 if(day){
  this.reportDataFromDate=(new Date()).toISOString();
}
if(week){
  let date = new Date();
  let day = date.getDay(),
  diff = date.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:0);
  this.reportDataFromDate=(new Date(date.setDate(diff))).toISOString();
}
if(month){
  let date = new Date();
  this.reportDataFromDate=(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)).toISOString();
}
```

Comment: for custom date selection how can i take using this if condition as in selction box i mentioned all  day,week,month

Comment: day=`reportType==1`, month=`reportType==7` and so on. Please put my code inside your code and test.

Comment: but what about to date ? and type string is not assignable to date i got this error and i gave variable like this  reportDataFromDate:Date;
  reportDataToDate:Date;

Comment: In all options to date is current date. Ionic by default use current date but you can use `this.reportDataToDate=(new Date()).toISOString();`

Comment: when im selecting the current day date i mean 2017-10-06 as from and to date im getting the data of 2017-10-05 also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156116/discussion-between-madpop-and-amin-arghavani).